# How to get devices Cell IDs under same BTS?

Tags: android, gsm, telephony, telecommunication, cellular-network

I have to develop an android application that has to get all mobile devices info in same Telco BTS as mine phone. Can I get all other mobile devices cell IDs?

Comment: Probably not. You'll be invading the privacy of the owners of those devices, so GSM and the mobile operators won't allow it. 
Unless the application is being written for the telco, in which case they may have an API to query this information.
You should rather have a centralized server that tracks all users of your application after they've opted in to allow it to use their location and then go from there.

Comment: @Wernsey Yes, I will develop the application for telco. I only have to send a broadcast to all the neighboring mobile devices, just exploring if there is any way I can do it without using an API/Server.

Comment: @ZeeshanAli .. Sorry bro for not providing a good solution

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you mention your requirement is 'I only have to send a broadcast to all the neighboring mobile devices'.

There is actually a solution built into most deployed GSM networks to do this already - it is called Cell Broadcast (or sometimes SMS-CB).

It is usually intended for emergency situations and allows an operator to send a message to all the devices in a given cell efficiently and even when the network is congested.

There is also a newer standard eMBMS which is similar concept but designed for multimedia broadcast, so maybe suitable to more commercial applications. This is not so well deployed at the moment, AFAIK.

Either way, the API's are in the Telco's domain and not available to a device unless the Telco has provided a special service for this.

As others have pointed out, a regular Android device will not have the ability to discover all its peers or to message everyone in the same cell, although a telco could provide a web service that the device could call if they wished.

The division between the 'phone' part of an Android phone and the 'app or computer' part of the device is strictly defined in Android - the intent is not only to protect privacy etc but also to protect the phone functionality and the network from malicious or malfunctioning apps.